# When is spark groupby preferred over reducebykey?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

My dataset is pretty big and I would like to understand when `groupby` makes sense over `reducebykey`?

Comment: Can you be more precise about the context here ? I'm pretty sure you mean "dataset" as "bunch of data" and not Spark Dataset type, right ?  Because there is no  `reduceByKey` on Datasets. Are you using RDDs ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

reduceByKey performs map side combine which reduces the amount of data sent over the network during shuffle and thereby also reduces the amount of data reduced. Where possible, use reducebyKey